# Clang vs gcc std::crbegin with boost::iterator_range

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, clang, c++14

Clang 3.8.1 with libc++ compiles the following program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3};

    const auto range = boost::make_iterator_range(v);

    std::copy(std::crbegin(range), std::crend(range), std::ostream_iterator<int> {std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But gcc 6.1.0 with libstdc++ does not. First line of gcc error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'crbegin(const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> > >&
```

Who is right?

**Note**: Boost version 1.61

Comment: What errors does gcc give?

Comment: @aschepler I've added the first line of the error - the rest doesn't add much. Same for `std::crend`. I actually think gcc is correct here - there is no `rbegin` or `rend` member method in `boost::iterator_range`. I just don't quite understand how Clang is making one!

Comment: @Daniel : Are you using Clang with libc++ or libstdc++? If the former, presumably it calls `std::make_reverse_iterator(range.begin())` if no `rbegin` member function is present. If the latter, then good question indeed...

Comment: @ildjarn libc++. That's what I suspected too, but is that correct behaviour?

Comment: @Daniel : I don't know, but if that's your real question then you need some serious editing here to reflect that (and probably the `language-lawyer` tag). I.e, your question presently seems to be asking about GCC, but your real question is in regards to libc++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a [bug in libc++](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=28927); `std::crbegin` is delegating to `rbegin`, but by calling it unqualified it's picking up [`boost::rbegin`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/range/rbegin.hpp) ([documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/functions.html)):

```
template <class _Cp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
auto crbegin(const _Cp& __c) -> decltype(rbegin(__c))
{
    return rbegin(__c);
    //     ^-- unqualified, allows ADL
}
```

This is contrary to **[iterator.range]**, which says that `crbegin` should delegate to `std::rbegin` only:

> `template <class C> constexpr auto crbegin(const C& c) -> decltype(std::rbegin(c));`
>
> 14 -  *Returns:* `std::rbegin(c)`.

Libc++'s implementations of `cbegin`, `cend` and `crend` have the same bug.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report.

Comment: And now it is fixed.